# Как правильно организовать БД из 4-х таблиц?

Tags: access

ИСПОЛЬЗУЕТСЯ: Access

Имеется три таблицы:
            - 00_tb1;
            - 00_tb2;
            - 00_tb3;
    Данные в таблицы поступают по средствам импорта или ввода

**ВОПРОС**
1. Как правильно и грамотно сделать чтобы данные стекались в таблицу "00_tb_4"?
2. Как сделать действия обозначенные на схеме (см. скрин)?
3. Как сделать, чтобы во всех таблицах можно было вносить изменения в ячейку таблицы (через таблицу или через форму) и эти изменения отображались во всех таблицах где данная запись отображается?

Ссылка на [файл](http://dropmefiles.com/daIn2)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вообще-то на этом сайте даются ответы на конкретные вопоросы, когда что-то пытался сделать, но не получилось. Для решения задач по техничекому заданию этот ресурс не предназначен. Начните делать  и задавайте вопросы, когда что-то не будет получаться